# What is the best approach to this plling and processing with Spring 4 and Quartz scheduling?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I am using `Spring 4.2.x` and `Quartz 2.1`. 
My requirement is that, I need to poll `database` at certain interval (say every 30 seconds) and pull 5 records at a time and schedule them for processing. At any given point of time, only 5 should be submitted for processing.

For example, if 5 are submitted, one of them completed, then I need to pull another one and submit it so 5 of them are constantly processed.

I can write a cron trigger and poll the `database` and pull 5 records at a time and submit them as `Job` for processing. But if none of first batch of 5 are not processed (i.e. still being processed), then I should not be submitting again. I have to wait until at least one of them is finished, then submit x number of jobs to meet 5 limit.

What is the approach? Do I need to use countdownlatch or something I can do within `spring/quartz` that can handle this scenario?

Does Quartz thread count (`org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount`) help here?

Comment: i think this problem needs to be solved using some message queueing software instead of quartz. There is not much scheduling involved. You want you ensure that you dont cross the max concurrent limit. With message queues like rabbitmq, activemq .. you can ensure this max concurrent limit by instantiating those many consumers. When one message is processed, next one will be picked from queue by itself

Comment: I need to poll at a constant interval, and if I find something in db that should be processed, then I need to process them 5 at a time. To put Messaging in the mix, I need to replace DB with queue (which is not possible), and executing 5 tasks at a time cannot be done with messaging. Messaging helps here in some way.. But I cannot replace components/libraries here.

Comment: you dont hav to replace db.you can bring in a queueing mechanism. This is a Producer Consumer problem with constraints. You will have a queue where producer puts messages and consumer which will pick messages and process. Here your queue will be bounded by size 5. Why executing 5 tasks cannot be done without messaging? If you have 5 consumers to consumer messages, then at any instant at max only 5 messages will be getting processed. In my opinion, you must queues here. If not queueing software, you can have a look at implementations of java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue with bounded property

Comment: I cannot add another layer of complexity here (Messaging), though I wish I could. However, I will check if BlockingQueue helps here.